# Can I setup a new .cpp file comment-template so that the filename and date will autofill?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am in the process of creating a new template for all of my .cpp files. I am using a similar block-style to that found in Code Complete, 2nd ed. and I am trying to have the date and filename autofill based on the system's time and the entered filename. What I have so far:

```
/**********************************************************************
filename: filename.cpp

class: class_name
author: author_name
date: date

Purpose goes here Purpose goes here Purpose goes here Purpose goes here
Purpose goes here Purpose goes here Purpose goes here Purpose goes here
Based on Pg. 789 "Code Complete" 2nd ed.
*********************************************************************/
```

edit: I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio Community 2015 as IDE and text editor

Comment: What operating system / IDE / editor / etc.?

Comment: Windows 10, Visual Studio Community 2015 as IDE and text editor.

Comment: I'm going to take my turn at being "that guy" and suggest that you don't actually want those fields anyway. Including the filename and the date in the file itself is redundant, since that data is already kept for you by the filesystem and/or your version control system (you *are* using a version control system like SVN or git, aren't you? If not, you should be).  Keeping a separate copy of that information in the file itself is unnecessary, and the text will inevitably not get updated after a while and then it will just be misinformation, not to mention a cause of unwanted noise in your diffs.

Comment: I'd partially agree with Jeremy, however, keeping the date and system information may be useful for the binary. Consider scenario: you extract date and sys info into a header: version.hpp. You include this file somewhere and print out it it's contents during init. This way, whatever the binary, you'll keep the *compilation* date. Also, keep this file outside any code repository...

Comment: Is this really a c++ question?  I'll admit it's an interesting question, but it seems more like a question about an IDE.

Comment: Good point. I think you're right.

edit: I have changed the tag from 'C++' to 'visual-studio-2015-comm'